Highlighted point is different in PyVista and Blender
I'm working with a point cloud 3D body data, and i manually  highligt certain points on the scan in blender. I treid visually the cordinates on the point on pyvista but the location of the poibt seems to far off (somewhere at the back) even after setting the location and rotation  as follows:
import pyvista as pv

import numpy as np


import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np

pcd_pv = pv.read('../slider/slidder002.obj')

pcd_pv.points -= np.mean(pcd_pv.points, axis=0)
pcd_pv.points /= np.max(np.abs(pcd_pv.points))
pcd_pv.rotate_y(180) # rotations parameters from blender
pcd_pv.rotate_x(180)
pcd_pv.rotate_z(295)
highlight_point = [0.007935, 0.162809, 0.098870]  # cordinates on the eye extracted from blender  
highlight_point = np.array(highlight_point)

type here

index = pcd_pv.find_closest_point(highlight_point)
print(f"Closest index for the highlight point: {index}")
plotter = pv.Plotter()
plotter.add_mesh(pcd_pv, point_size=5, render_points_as_spheres=True)
plotter.add_mesh(pv.PolyData(highlight_point), color='red', point_size=10, render_points_as_spheres=True)
plotter.add_text('Highlighted Point', font_size=18)
plotter.add_point_labels([highlight_point], [str(index)], point_size=10, text_color='red', font_size=12)
plotter.show()`

[point on the 3D scan](https://i.sstatic.net/AJc2Y558.png

Right after reading the mesh with PyVista, you shift the points to have zero center and divide by the maximum coordinate component of the points. This 1. is an unusual transformation, and 2. is surprising because you'd have to do the same transformation in blender in order to match coordinates. Naively I'd assume that you'd just load the mesh both in blender and in PyVista and work with raw point coordinates. Can you confirm that the same transformation is supposed to apply in Blender and PyVista? Without an actual example mesh it will be hard for anyone else to debug your issue.
